# Reinterpret List[Any] as a List[Int]

Tags: list, scala, types, casting, type-conversion

I have a `List` that I am sure only contains `Int` members, but the list is of type `List[Any]`. I need to sum the numbers in this list, but I can't use the `+` operator because it is not defined on `Any`.

```
scala> val l = List[Any](1, 2, 3)
l: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
<console>:9: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int
 cannot be applied to (Any)
              l.foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
                              ^
```

I tried converting it to a `List[Int]` via `l.map(_.toInt)` but that of course failed for the exact same reason.

Given a `List[Any]` that is actually a list of ints, how can I convert it to a `List[Int]`?

For the curious, this is how I got here:

```
scala> val l = List(List("x", 1), List("y", 2))
l: List[List[Any]] = List(List(x, 1), List(y, 2))

scala> l.transpose
res0: List[List[Any]] = List(List(x, y), List(1, 2))
```

Comment: If you're sure that your list contains only ints you can do a `.map(_.asInstanceOf[Int])`, but then again, the syntax is horrible for a precise reason.

Comment: Or just `l.asInstanceOf[List[Int]]` which doesn't have the runtime cost.

Comment: @RobertHarvey well in the scala api you rarely find something as verbose as `asInstanceOf` and that's because type casting is a code smell, in my opinion even ending up with a `List[Any]` is a code smell, but of course it depends on the asker use case.

Comment: I agree that the `List[Any]` is a bit of a code smell, so I added some info to the question addressing how I got there. Maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @Ryan, they're both horrible, and they're both going to fail at runtime. If you're not absolutely sure the cast won't fail you shouldn't be using either.

Comment: @TravisBrown very true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The safest way to cast elements of a list is to use `collect`:

```
val l: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3)

val l2: List[Int] = l collect { case i: Int => i }
```

`collect` both filters and maps elements of a list, so any elements which are not ints will be ignored.  Only those elements which match the case statement will be included.

OTOH, the best way to fix this is to never have a `List[Any]` in the first place.  I'd address that rather than trying to cast.

Comment: I updated the question with info on how I got to the `List[Any]`. I'm not sure it is avoidable in this case, but maybe?

Comment: But why would you have a heterogenous list like that in the first place?

Comment: I'm generating test data for a service that does group-by operations. Since I'm creating the data for this test case, I know that the only thing I'm putting in column 2 is an `Int`. Since it's a test, I don't want to over architect it - I just want to convert my original test data to what I expect the group-by service to give back to me.

Comment: If the list elements are really representations of a row, it'd be better to use a tuple than a list.

Comment: `List(("x", 1),("y",2)).transpose` wouldn't be available with tuples.

Comment: @CoryKlein, no, but `.unzip` will, and it's type-safe.

Comment: OMG when am I going to memorize all of these awesome lambdas. Thanks @TravisBrown. I love Scala.